# Ruby: What is the easiest method to update Hash values?

Tags: ruby, hash

Say:

```
h = { 1 => 10, 2 => 20, 5 => 70, 8 => 90, 4 => 34 }
```

I would like to change each value `v` to `foo(v`), such that `h` will be:

```
h = { 1 => foo(10), 2 => foo(20), 5 => foo(70), 8 => foo(90), 4 => foo(34) }
```

What is the most elegant way to achieve this ?

Comment: Very closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189161/changing-every-value-in-a-hash-in-ruby

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can use `update` (alias of `merge!`) to update each value using a block:

```
hash.update(hash) { |key, value| value * 2 }
```

Note that we're effectively merging `hash` with itself. This is needed because Ruby will call the block to resolve the merge for any keys that collide, setting the value with the return value of the block.

Comment: In my quick benchmark this was even faster than the `each` method by about 20%!

Comment: Be careful when you are trying to use it in Rails, where the Hash is really the HashWithIndifferentAccess and has different behavior when it comes to handling blocks passed to `update` and `merge`.

About a month ago someone proposed change to fix it:

 https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7519

Comment: `Hash#update` is an alias for `Hash#merge!`. [These docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) mention that most docs use `merge!`. I personally prefer to use merge!, as my mind stays in hash mode, whereas when I see "update" I can't help but think of ActiveRecord.

Comment: Tyler Collier - .update() is cleaner to read. It has nothing to do with ActiveRecord, it existed way before active record existed.

Answer (score 26):

Rails (**and Ruby 2.4+ natively**) have `Hash#transform_values`, so you can now do `{a:1, b:2, c:3}.transform_values{|v| foo(v)}`

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values

If you need it to work in nested hashes as well, Rails now has `deep_transform_values`[(source)](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_transform_values):

```
hash = { person: { name: 'Rob', age: '28' } }

hash.deep_transform_values{ |value| value.to_s.upcase }
# => {person: {name: "ROB", age: "28"}}
```

Comment: Probably didn't get the "answer" because its Rails and not only Ruby.

Comment: That is only one reason - the other is that the hash.update() variant is pure ruby and will work ALWAYS whereas rails specifically requires add-ons. The less dependencies, the better.

Comment: @Alex ruby 2.4.0 add it the core. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values

Answer (score 12):

This will do:

```
h.each {|k, v| h[k] = foo(v)}
```

Comment: Now with new Ruby (from 2.4 onwards I think), this is easier `h.transform_values! { |v| foo(v) }`

Answer (score 6):

The following is slightly faster than @Dan Cheail's for large hashes, and is slightly more functional-programming style:

```
new_hash = Hash[old_hash.map {|key, value| key, foo(value)}]
```

`Hash#map` creates an array of key value pairs, and `Hash.[]` converts the array of pairs into a hash.

Comment: Indeed; this is the 'pro' way to do it, although the syntax may be a bit mind-bending if you're not used to Ruby's specifics.

Comment: Also, in Ruby 1.8, you may need to explicitly surround `key, foo(value)` with `[]` - I was getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to do it; the most straight-forward way would be to use `Hash#each` to update a new hash:

```
new_hash = {}
old_hash.each do |key, value|
  new_hash[key] = foo(value)
end
```

Comment: I want to change the values in-place, not creating a new Hash.

Comment: @misha...u can change values in place by replacing `new_hash[key]` by `old_hash[key]`