# Changing a value of a key

Tags: ruby

Is there a shorter way to change the value of a key?

```
 my_array.each do |x| 
    if my_hash.key?(x) 
      my_hash[x] += 1
    else
      my_hash[x] = 1
    end
  end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: What is the easiest method to update Hash values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215713/ruby-what-is-the-easiest-method-to-update-hash-values)

Comment: @Зелёный, what if a key doesn't exist, will it still work?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp : Check my answer if this is what you are looking for then. otherwise let me know so I can update my answer accordingly

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp it just possible duplicate =).

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter:

```
my_array.each do |x| 
  my_hash[x] ||= 0
  my_hash[x] += 1
end
```

Comment: but I don't want it to be 0 by default.

Comment: It won't be zero since you add 1 right after initialisation

Comment: I don't want it to have any default value.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case it's probably easiest to give the hash a default value:

```
my_hash = Hash.new(1)
=> {}
my_hash[:x]
=> 1
my_hash[:y] += 1
=> 2
```

Please note that this only makes sense if the default value is immutable, otherwise the reference will be shared between all keys.

Comment: how can y be equal to 2?

Comment: Because it had a default value of 1. If you don't want that, initialize the hash with `Hash.new(0)`.

Comment: I don't want it to have a default value at all. I want to upsert a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator to write your statement on one line.

```
my_array.each {|x| my_hash.key?(x) ? my_hash[x].next : my_hash[x] = 1}
```

You can also use the **next** method if you are increasing a value by just 1.