# Using .update to update values

Tags: ruby

If we have a hash and we want to update one of the values or keys we can easily use the .`update` method like the following

```
def foo(params)
    params+=1
end

hsh = {:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3}

hsh.update(hsh) do |key,oldVal|
    foo(oldVal)
end

p hsh
```

However suppose a new `hash`, and I want to copy its properties into another `hash` and add one to the value. How would I exactly do this? Here is my attempt

```
def foo(params)
    params+=1
end
new_hsh = {:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3}
hsh = {}
hsh.update(new_hsh) do |key,value,newVal|
    newVal = foo(value)
end

p hsh
```

Which outputs `{:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3}`. So it is copying `new_hsh`, but not updating the `value`.

According to docs

> Adds the contents of other_hash to hsh. If no block is specified, entries with duplicate keys are overwritten with the values from other_hash, otherwise the value of each duplicate key is determined by calling the block with the key, its value in hsh and its value in other_hash.

So it is copying like the docs say.. but how can I update it?

Thanks

EDIT

tried

```
def foo(params)
    params+=1
end
new_hsh = {:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3}
hsh = {}
hsh.update(new_hsh) do |key,value,newVal|
    foo(newVal)
end

p hsh
```

Comment: In your first snippet, you're not updating _one_ of values. You're updating __all__ of them.

Comment: Yes sorry, that is what I wanted to do.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, do you know why my edited snippet does not work?

Comment: of course. Because `update` doesn't find any duplicate keys (the receiver hash is empty) and therefore does not call the block.

Comment: I see. Is `update` not useful for transferring one things from one hash to another then? I know there are other ways but I am curious

Comment: Why, `.update` is quite usable for this. It does it very well. It's just that you require something on top of it. :)

Comment: I suggest `hsh = new_hsh.map{|k, v| [k, v+1]}.to_h`

Comment: I see. so its possible and I just haven't thought of a solution with `.update` yet right? XD

Comment: no, `.update` is a wrong hammer for this task.

Comment: In the docs it says `update(other_hash) → hsh`, so when do you want to use `update` to manipulate another hash based on one?

Comment: You only use `.update` to copy other hash as is. It is not suited for any additional pre-processing.

Comment: lol oh ok. You would think the method for that would be like `.copy` or something, which probably exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another answer. This works but also modifies the new_hsh. But you need to set the hsh = new_hsh before calling update on hsh.

```
def foo(params)
params+=1
end

new_hsh = {:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3}
hsh = new_hsh
hsh.update(hsh) do |key,value|
    hsh[key] = foo(value)
end

p hsh
```

Comment: yeah thats what I said at the top.

Comment: This updates `new_hsh` because `hashes` are objects, and its being changed by reference from the line `hsh=new_hsh` right?

Answer (score 1):

Dont pass in 3 parameters. Just pass in 2 like this. Iterate over each key, value pair of your new_hsh and set the key equal to the new value after being passed to the foo method and push into your hsh.

```
def foo(params)
params+=1
end
new_hsh = {:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3}
hsh = {}
new_hsh.each do |key,value|
    hsh[key] = foo(value)
end

p hsh
```

Comment: Great, this does indeed work, how do i implement this using `.update` though?

Comment: Try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215713/ruby-what-is-the-easiest-method-to-update-hash-values

Comment: My working example is the same as the suggested ones in that question. I just wanted to know if I can do this with `update`,  with regards to a new hash. Is there any way to do so?