# How to select keys from hash and strip parts of the keyname with ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I have a config hash in my ruby project and I want to pick certain keys with their value to have them as a separate hash.

```
Project.config.to_h.select{ |k,v| k[/db_/] }
=> {:db_name => value, .... }
```

This returns me nicely all the `k,v` that I need. But I also want to strip the `db_` from the keynames so that it returns me

```
=> {:name => value, ....}
```

I tried something like

```
Project.config.to_h.select{ |k,v| k[/db_/] }.each_key { |k| k.to_s.gsub(/db_/) }
```

But it returns the same hash like the above example. Any idea or suggestions to get this as a smooth one or two liner?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing every value in a hash in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189161/changing-every-value-in-a-hash-in-ruby)

Comment: @WandMaker: OP wants to modify the keys.

Comment: @undur_gongor  Options given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189161/changing-every-value-in-a-hash-in-ruby. will work for keys too

Comment: @WandMaker: True, but does the question qualify as a duplicate then?

Comment: @undur_gongor  It says "possible duplicate", I will let moderators decide the merit

Answer (score 0):

`inject` to the rescue (assuming the `db_` is in the beginning):

```
Project.config.to_h.inject({}) do | a, (k, v) |
  k =~ /\Adb_/ ? a.update($' => v) : a
end
```

`inject` can be used to iterate through an enumerable data structure and build any kind of output in the course.

`$'` is a magic variable containing the portion of the string after a successful regexp match.

Answer (score 0):

So let's break down your solution and see what's wrong with it:

```
Project.config.to_h.select{ |k,v| k[/db_/] }.each_key { |k| k.to_s.gsub(/db_/) }
```

So:

```
k.to_s.gsub(/db_/)
```

is creating a new object (and not mutating the keys like you would expect), in this case an enumerator, when you don't pass `gsub` a second argument it returns an enumerator, so let's assume you did:

```
k.to_s.gsub(/db_/, "")
```

This would be creating new objects and not mutating the keys in the hash(`to_s` would create a new string object, and `gsub` doesn't mutate, instead creates a new object, `gsub!` is the mutant version)

Now let's assume the keys were strings and you could even mutate them (with `gsub!`), ruby would not let you mutate them in place, else ruby hash would be broken, when a string is used as a key it is `frozen`, see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html#5B-5D-3D-method

> key should not have its value changed while it is in use as a key (an unfrozen String passed as a key will be duplicated and frozen).

So with this knowledge how would I implement this:

```
Project.config.to_h.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), hsh|
   next unless k[/db_/]  # skip every key that doesn't match the regex (if you want the keys to not have part of them stripped then you can use an if/else along with the next line)
   hsh[k.to_s.sub(/db_/, "")] = v
end
```

Comment: `to_s` does not create a new object if `k` is already a string.